# What are the consequences of this simple property of $L^1$ functions?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, lp-spaces

I came across the following statement:

> Let $f\in L^1(\mathbb R,\mathbb R)$. Then $$\forall \varepsilon>0 \ \ \exists \delta>0 \ \ \text{such that for all open sets } U\subset\mathbb R \text{ with Vol}(U)<\delta: \left| \int_U f \right|<\varepsilon$$

It reminded me on uniform continuity, and since the latter shows up very frequently, I was wondering if this statement has any immediate consequences. Or maybe it's a special case of a more general theorem? How can the statement be generalized?

Comment: This is actually [Absolute Continuity of the Lebesgue Integral](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/535185/absolute-continuity-of-the-lebesgue-integral)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be generalized: this is a notion called [uniform integrability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_integrability).

It gives nice convergence properties in measure theory (in particular a generalization of the dominated convergence theorem).