# A basic question on the existence of expectation?

Tags: probability-theory

$E\big[\sqrt(X)\big] <\infty \implies \sqrt(X) <\infty$ a.s $\implies X< \infty$ a.s $ \implies E[X] <\infty$

The expectation is computed wrt to the probability measure . So why the the last implication not true?
I mean the way I see it is by considering X as a simple measurable function which can take only finite value i.e it is bounded (except ofcourse on a measure zero set) and therefore its expectation should exist. Where am I going wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mistake is in the last implication. Just because $X<\infty$ a.s. does not mean that $E(X) < \infty$. You can only say anything if you make the stronger assumption that $X<M<\infty$ a.s. In this case $E(X) < M < \infty$.

For instance, you can have $X$ whose probability density is $1/x^2$ for $x \geq 1$ and $0$ otherwise. Then $X<\infty$ a.s., but $E(X) = \int_1^\infty \frac1{x} dx = \lim_{b \to \infty} \ln(b) = \infty$. This example also satisfies your initial hypothesis about $E(\sqrt{X})$, since $x^{-3/2}$ *is* integrable on $[1,\infty)$.

Comment: But doesn't $X< \infty$ imply there exists an $M$ such that $X<M$ a.s? I mean if X is finite then it has to have a bound say M? What is wrong with this reasoning?

Comment: @user3503589 Just because $X$ is finite at each $\omega$ does not mean it is has a uniform bound independent of $\omega$. Look again at my example: $\{ X=\infty \}$ has probability zero, yet $\{ X \geq M \}$ has positive probability for any $M>0$. This also does not really have anything to do with probability or even with measure theory: if you consider any real-valued unbounded function, say $f(x)=x$ on $\mathbb{R}$, then there are no points where it is infinite (because it is real-valued), but it is still not bounded.

Comment: Your counter-example clearly shows that the last implication fails. We are trying to compute $\int_{Omega} X dP$ and if say we have disjoint sets $(A_i)_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$ such that  $\bigcup_{i \in \mathbb{N}} A_i=1$ then if X takes only finite values , if I think in terms of simple functions wouldn't $\sum_i x_i*\mu(A_i) < \infty$?

Comment: For a more classical probabilistic example, you can look at a Gaussian random variable. These are again *not* bounded, yet they have finite expected value!

Comment: @user3503589 Each *separate* integral of a simple approximation of $X$ will be finite. But the integrals will grow without bound as you refine the approximation.

Comment: I think I understand what you mean. I was really troubled by the the misconception I held that if something is not infinity it is bounded. It might not be infinity but it might it can go higher than any M as your example demonstrates with a positive density. Thank you so much Ian . I am very grateful