# The asymptotic behavior of an absolutely continuous function with square integrable derivative

Tags: real-analysis, lp-spaces

Let $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be absolutely continuous and assume that $f'\in L^2([0,1])$ and that $f(0) = 0.$ Show that the following limit exists and compute its value: $ \lim_{x \to 0}  x^{-1/2} f(x).$

---

My approach since $f$ is absolutely continuous $f'(x)$ exists almost everywhere. And by Mean Value Theorem  $f(x) -f(0) =f'(c)(x-0)$ for some $c \in (0, x)$. Which further  $f'$ is in $L^2$ of $[0 1]$ which implies the square integral is finite. but from here how can i proceed?

Comment: There is no Mean Value Theorem for absolutely continuous functions. There _is_ a Fundamental Theorem of Calculus: $f(x)-f(0)=\int_0^x f'(t)\,dt$.

Comment: Yea You are right. I am sorry. next what to do to find the limit?

Comment: Hint: Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.

Comment: i did apply there then i got limit is 0 am i right?@John Dawkins

Comment: Show us your reasoning, if you would.

Comment: I edited the first paragraph. Right-click on it to find the underlying LaTeX, then please edit the second paragraph.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in a comment by John Dawkins, you need the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality:

$$
f(x)^2 \le \left(\int_0^x |f'(t)|\,dt\right)^2\le 
\int_0^x 1\,dt \int_0^x |f'(t)|^2\,dt = x \int_0^x |f'(t)|^2\,dt
$$
Here the factor $\int_0^x |f'(t)|^2\,dt$ tends to zero as $x\to 0$, and the conclusion $x^{-1}f(x)^2\to0$ follows.

Comment: I must be missing something but why should the factor $\int_0^x |f'(t)|^2\,dt$ tends to zero as $x\to \infty$?

Comment: By the [Absolute continuity of the Lebesgue integral](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/535185)

Comment: I am truly sorry but I still don't get your point. Isn't the function $|f'(x)|^2$ positive so $F(x)=\int_0^x |f'(t)|^2\,dt$ is an increasing function of $x$ with $F(0)=0$?

Comment: But isn't that what you wrote in your answer (I'm getting very confused here)? Didn't you really mean $x\to 0$?

Comment: Right, was a typo. Fixed