# Show that for any bounded shape, you can make a straight cut in any direction to create halves of equal area

Tags: real-analysis

On an infinite frying pan, there is a bounded pancake. Prove that one can make a straight cut in any given direction (that is, parallel to a given line) that splits the pancake in halves of equal area.

I think that you can use intermediate value theorem, but I'm not quite sure where to start or how to apply the theorem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the outline of a solution. For every nonzero vector $v \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ consider the half-space defined as $H_{\lambda} = x \cdot v \geq \lambda$. For any bounded region $B$, let $B_{\lambda} = H_{\lambda} \cap B$. This corresponds to the part of $B$ on side of a cut that runs parallel to any vector perpendicular to $v$. Fix the vector $v$ and define the function $f(\lambda) = \mbox{Volume}(B_\lambda)$. Show that $f(\lambda)$ is continuous, that $\lim_{\lambda \to \infty} f(\lambda) = 0$, and that $\lim_{\lambda \to -\infty} f(\lambda) = \mbox{Volume}(B)$. Finally, apply the intermediate value theorem.

Perhaps this picture might help:
[image]

Comment: A minor nitpick: we are assuming that $B$ is a bounded *and measurable* set, then exploiting the absolute continuity of the Lebesgue measure (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/535185/absolute-continuity-of-the-lebesgue-integral).

Comment: @ElchananSolomon Could you please explain why those limits turn out the way they do?  I don't see why f($\lambda$) would go to 0 as $\lambda$ goes to infinity?  Isn't f(\lambda) the volume of B$_{\lambda}$?  Why would the volume go to 0?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio We haven't done Lebesque Measure yet.  Is there a way to do this without involving that?

Comment: @VinnyChase: it depends on your definition of *area*. What is it?