# How can we show that $\mu\ll\nu$ iff $\lim_{\nu(S)\to0}\mu(S)=0$?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let

- $\Omega\subseteq2^\Omega$
- $\mathcal S\subseteq2^\Omega$
- $E$ be a normed $\mathbb R$-vector space
- $\mu:\mathcal S\to E$
- $\nu:\mathcal S\to[0,\infty)$

Write $\mu\ll\nu$, if $$\forall\varepsilon>0:\exists\delta>0:\forall S\in\mathcal S:\nu(S)<\delta\Rightarrow\left\|\mu(S)\right\|_E<\varepsilon\tag1\;.$$

> I want to show that if $\mathcal S$ is a $\sigma$-algebra and $\mu$ and $\nu$ are $\sigma$-additive, then $(1)$ is equivalent to $$\forall S\in\mathcal S:\nu(S)=0\Rightarrow\mu(S)=0\;.\tag2$$

Clearly, $(1)$ implies $(2)$. How can we show the other implication?

Comment: Is $E$ finite dimensional or could it also be infinite dimensional? I think that could change a lot the difficulty of the problem

Comment: @Lucio No additional assumptions on $E$. It can be infinite-dimensional.

Comment: Anyway, in the case $E=\mathbb{R}$, you can show 2) implies 1) by means of Radon-Nikodym theorem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon%E2%80%93Nikodym_theorem and aboslute continuity of Lebesgue integral https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/535185/absolute-continuity-of-the-lebesgue-integral

Comment: In the case $E$ is finite dimensional, wlog by choosing a basis you can work with $E=\mathbb{R}^n$ and in that case $\mu$ will be of the form $\mu=(\mu_1,\ldots, \mu_n)$ with $\mu_i$ real valued and $\mu_i <<\nu$ so you can reduce to the previous case

Comment: The problem with infinite dimensional $E$ is that in general "good" basis do not exist and Radon-Nikodym theorem does not hold, so none of the above resonings work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the standard argument in Rudin's book.

If (1) is false, there exists $\varepsilon>0$ and sets $E_n\in\mathcal S$ with $\nu(E_n)<2^{-n}$ and $\|\mu(E_n)\|\geq\varepsilon$. Then $|\mu|(E_n)\geq\varepsilon$, where $|\mu|$ is the *total variation* of $\mu$:
$$\tag{*}
|\mu|(F)=\sup\{\sum\|\mu(F_n)\|:\ F=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty F_n,\ \text{ disjoint}\}. 
$$
Of course, one needs to prove that (*) defines a measure, but this is also standard.

If $$B_n=\bigcup_{k\geq n}E_n,\ \ B=\bigcap_n B_n,$$ Then $\nu(B_n)<2^{-n+1}$ (after adding the geometric series) and $B_n\supset B_{n+1}$. By continuity of the measure, $\nu(B)=0$. Also 
$$
|\mu|(B)=\lim_n|\mu|(B_n)\geq\limsup_n|\mu|(E_n)\geq\varepsilon>0.
$$
Hence (2) fails. The contradiction shows that (2) implies (1).

Comment: Note that there is no need to explicitly assume *boundedness* of $\mu$: Since $\mu$ is $\sigma$-additive on a $\sigma$-algebra, it is *strongly additive* (i.e. $\left(\mu(S_n)\right)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is summable for all disjoint $(S_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\subseteq\mathcal S$) and hence bounded (i.e. $\sup_{S\in\mathcal S}\left\|\mu(S)\right\|_E<\infty$). (Don't sure what you mean by "uniformly" bounded, since $\mu$ doesn't depend on more than one parameter.)

Comment: Yes, you are right.