# Limit of an integral over a ball as the radius of the ball goes to zero 2

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $D(a,r)$ be an open ball in $\mathbb{R}^{k}$ ($ k\geq1 $), and  $f$ locally integrable function in $\mathbb{R}^{k}$. Do we have: 
$$\lim_{r\to 0}\int_{D(a,r)}f(t)dt=0?$$

Comment: Yes, by dominated convergence.

Comment: In physics there are cases where one uses point charges to describe fields. A point charge is represented by the Dirac delta function. If you integrate over a sphere around the point charge, and then shrink the radius to $+0$, what you get is a constant term, not necessarily zero.

Comment: The question says explicitly "$f$ is a locally integrable _function_" ruling out the possibility that $f$ is a Dirac's delta.

Comment: Lord Shark the Unknown: How would you deduce this from dominated convergence? I don't see it.

Comment: Why would it not be 0? Out of all the numbers out there, such as: 1, 15, 0, 92, 5673, -14i, why would it be anything other than 0 ?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The answer is YES. This is a classic result called "absolute continuity of The Lebesgue integral", for example see 
rmh52 (https://math.stackexchange.com/users/35961/rmh52), Absolute continuity of the Lebesgue integral, URL (version: 2017-02-03): [Absolute continuity of the Lebesgue integral](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/535185)