# Let $\lambda(A_n) \to 0$. Is $\int_{A_n} f \mathrm d \lambda \to 0$?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $f \in L_1([0, 1])$ and $A_n \subset [0, 1]$ be measurable such that $\lambda(A_n) \to 0$ where $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure.

> Can we prove that $\int_{A_n} f \mathrm d \lambda \to 0$ as $n \to +\infty$? If not, is it true if we impose more that $A_{n} \supset A_{n+1}$?

**My attempt:** If $A_{n} \supset A_{n+1}$ then
$$
a_n :=\int_{A_n} |f| \mathrm d \lambda
$$
decreases as $n \to \infty$. However, I could not prove that $a_n \to 0$.

Comment: Integral over $A_n$ is equivalent to multiplying $f$ by the indicator of $A_n$. Since $f$ is $L^1$ you can apply DCT.

Comment: @Leonid It seems we need $A_{n} \supset A_{n+1}$ to apply DCT, right?

Comment: No, why do you say that? The sequence $1_{A_n}f$ is dominated by $|f|$ and its pointwise limit is the $0$ function a.e. (since $f$ is $L^1$ it is finite a.e. hence the pointwise limit exists a.e. and is zero)

Comment: Actually never-mind the comment above. After having considered more carefully the pointwise convergence of that sequence, it seems that the above assumption is indeed required. Since intuitively one can construct a sequence which is shrinking but is "oscillating" through the points.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recall [the absolute continuity of Lebesgue integral](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/535185/absolute-continuity-of-the-lebesgue-integral?noredirect=1&lq=1): For each $\epsilon>0$, there is $\delta>0$ such that for all measurable $E\subset[0,1]$ with $\lambda(E)<\delta$, we have
$$\int_E |f|\,d\lambda<\epsilon.$$

Now for this $\delta>0$, we can find $N>0$ such that $\lambda(A_n)<\delta$ for all $n>N$, so
$$\left|\int_{A_n}f\,d\lambda\right|\leq\int_{A_n}|f|\,d\lambda<\epsilon,\quad n>N.$$

We don’t need $A_{n+1}\subset A_n$.

Comment: Without $A_{n+1}\subset A_n$, is the result true for  a measure different from the Lebesgue one?

Comment: @Akira See the proof of absolute continuity [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/535185/absolute-continuity-of-the-lebesgue-integral). It seems to me from the proof that the absolute continuity also holds for other measures.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @Akira You’re welcome. I’m glad to help.