# Continuity of Lebesgue integral

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

I'm trying to solve the following problem from Klenke (3rd ed, exercise 4.2.1.)

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{A},\mu)$ be a measure space and let $f\in L^1(\mu)$. Show that for any $\epsilon>0$, there is an $A\in\mathcal{A}$ with $\mu(A)<\infty$ and $|\int_{A}fd\mu-\int fd\mu|<\varepsilon$.

I can show this if I can assume that $\mu$ is finite, i.e., $\mu(\Omega)<\infty$, by using the [continuity of Lebesgue integral](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/535185/absolute-continuity-of-the-lebesgue-integral). Specifically,

$$
|\int_{A}fd\mu-\int fd\mu| =|\int_{\Omega}fd\mu-\int_{\Omega\setminus A}fd\mu-\int fd\mu|
 =|\int_{\Omega\setminus A}fd\mu|
 \le \int_{\Omega\setminus A}|f|d\mu,
$$

so I can take $B:=\Omega\setminus A$ such that $\mu(B)<\delta$ and the RHS of the above is less than $\varepsilon$. Then, $\mu(A)=\mu(\Omega)-\delta$, so if $\mu(\Omega)<\infty$, we have $\mu(A)<\infty$.

But, how can I show this when $\mu$ is not finite? Can I somehow generalize the arguemnt above?

Comment: Use DCT on $|f| \chi_{\{ |f| \geq n\}}$.

Comment: If you assume $\mu$ to be $\sigma$-finite then you have $A_{n}$ disjoint such that $\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb{N}}A_{n}=\Omega$ with $\mu(A_{k})<\infty$ . So $\displaystyle f\mathbf{1}_{\bigcup_{k=1}^{n}A_{k}}\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}f$ . Now you can use DCT to find $N$ such that for all $n\geq N$, you have $\bigg|\displaystyle\int_{\Omega}f-\int_{\Omega}f\mathbf{1}_{\bigcup_{k=1}^{n}A_{k}}\bigg|<\epsilon$ for all $n\geq N$ and in particular you can take $\displaystyle A=\bigcup_{k=1}^{N}A_{k}$.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker Ofcourse. Having a complete brain freeze today.

Comment: Why is the function note integrable when $\mu$ is not $\sigma$-finite?

Comment: @keepfrog ignore michaels's comment. It was in reply to one of my comments which I deleted.

Comment: @Mr.GandalfSauron Does it mean your answer is not complete because it does not cover the case where $\mu$ is $\sigma$-finite? Or, as Michael's comment suggests, if it is not $\sigma$-finite then $f\notin L^1$? In that case, why can we conclude that $f\notin L^1$?

Comment: @FZan I see that I can apply the DCT to $f \mathbb{I}_{\{|f|>1/n\}}$ in a similar manner as Mr.Gandalf's comment.  But in the case, how can we ensure that $\mu(\{|f|>1/n\})<\infty$ for some large $n$?

Comment: Well you do know $\int |f|$ is finite, try using Chebiyev.

Comment: @FZan Ah I see thank you

Comment: @keepfrog The comment I gave answers the question for $\mu$ being  $\sigma$-finite. Additionally I added a comment that what does FZan's comment achieve since we cannot know whether $\{|f|\geq n\}$ has finite measure. To which Michael pointed out that if those sets do not have finite measure then $|f|$ cannot possibly be integrable. So as I said, as of now, ignore Michel's comment.

Comment: But still, @FZan 's comment does not help us see whether $\{|f|\leq n\}$ has finite measure.(Which is what is required by FZan's method as you would have to set $A=\{|f|\leq N\}$ to get $\int_{|f|\geq N}|f|<\epsilon$. For example, when $f$ is identically $0$, then all such $\{|f|\leq n\}$ have infinite measure(if $\mu$ is not finite) but still $f$ is integrable. So I don't really see how FZan's comment would help there.

Comment: @Mr.GandalfSauron  This is what I had in mind: If we apply the DCT to $f\mathbb{I}_{\{|f|>1/n\}}$ instead, then for large $n$ we have $|\int f\mathbb{I}_{\{|f|>1/n\}} d\mu - \int f d\mu|<\epsilon$. Thus, we can take $A=\{|f|>1/n\}$, and by Chebyshev $\mu(A)\le n \int |f| d\mu < \infty$.

Comment: @keepfrog It seems good to me. You can post it as an answer yourself.

Answer (score 3):

I have figured out an answer with the community's help in the comment section, so I post that for completeness:

We can apply the DCT to $f\mathbb{I}_{\{|f|>1/n\}}$, so we have $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int f\mathbb{I}_{\{|f|>1/n\}}d\mu=\int fd\mu$. This implies that, for large $n$, we have $|\int f\mathbb{I}_{\{|f|>1/n\}}d\mu-\int fd\mu|<\epsilon$. Therefore, we can take $A=\{|f|>1/n\}$. Finally, by Chebyshev's inequality,
$$
\mu(A)=\mu(\{|f|>1/n\})\le n\int|f|d\mu<\infty,
$$
where the last inequality is from $f\in L^1(\mu)$.